# ERROR UNMARSHALLER AL LEER ARCHIVOS DE UN XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

CÓDIGO: // Creamos el contexto indicando la clase raíz en este caso Universidad.java

```
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Universidad.class);

    //Creamos el Marshaller, convierte el java bean en una cadena XML
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();

    //Limpiamos el xml si existe para imprimirlo correctamente
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

    // Lo visualizamos con system out
    //m.marshal(miUniversidad, System.out);

    // Escribimos en el archivo
    m.marshal(miUniversidad, new File("c:\\temporal\\universidad.xml"));

    // Visualizamos ahora los datos del documento UNIVERSIDAD.XML creado
    System.out.println("------------ Leo el XML ---------");

    //Se crea Unmarshaller en el cotexto de la clase Libreria
    Unmarshaller unmars = context.createUnmarshaller();

    //Utilizamos el método unmarshal, para obtener datos de un Reader
    Universidad miUniversidad2 = (Universidad) unmars.unmarshal(new FileReader("c:\\temporal\\universidad.xml"));

    //Recuperamos el array list y visualizamos
    ArrayList<Departamento> listaUniversidad = miUniversidad2.getlistaDepartamento();

    //recorremos el arraylist

    for (Departamento dep : listaUniversidad) {

        System.out.println("Nombre del departamento: "+ dep.getNombre());
        System.out.println("Edificio del departamento: "+ dep.getEdificio());
        System.out.println("Profesores del departamento: ");

        ArrayList<Profesor> listaprofesores =  dep.getprofesores();
        for (Profesor profe : listaprofesores) {
            System.out.println("\tNombre profesor: " + profe.getNombrep() + " , Especialidad: " + profe.getEspecialidad());
        }

    }
```

---

MUESTRA EN CONSOLA:
------------ Leo el XML ---------

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.addToPack(Lister.java:304)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.addToPack(Lister.java:268)
>     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Scope.add(Scope.java:121)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty$ReceiverImpl.receive(ArrayERProperty.java:213)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.endElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:614)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:180)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)
>     at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown
>   Source)   at FicheroUniversidad.main(FicheroUniversidad.java:101)

Comment: espera... no estas cerrando el fichero antes de abrirlo ni nada, no??

Comment: No sin abrir fichero ni nada, no se porque me aparece